# How to hide title and link html tag using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, css3pie

I have been trying to hide title and link tag using internal css, but it is not working.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png">
<title>app · Streamlit</title>
```

I wanted to hide these two using css or js, Any solution?

Comment: Could you say why you want to hide the title? Are you wanting to put something else in its place?

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot touch the browser chrome. It can't change the favicon or title in the address bar / browser tab / window title bar.

It can only affect the document in the viewport.

Comment: any other solution using JavaScript?

Comment: @MuzammilDafedar Yes you could remove these elements using javascript. Removing the title will then result in the page's url being put into place.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that you can do with CSS.

> `<title>app · Streamlit</title>`

This is how you could set an empty text:

```js
document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = '';
```

Or you could also remove that tag:

```js
document.querySelector('title').remove();
```

> `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png">`

Removing the value `./favicon.png` will not help, so you will need to set an empty icon:

```js
document.querySelector('link[rel~="shortcut"]').setAttribute('href', 'data:image/x-icon');
```